# Did I correctly set-up my API for this weather app?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am working with a weather app api and I am trying to display weather Data based off what the users inserts in the form. For some reason the data is not displaying. I have gone through the code 10 times, and I cant seem to find the error.

Can anyone take a look at point out where I have gone wrong?

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('submitWeather').click(function() {
    var city = $('#city').val();

    if (city != '') {

      $.ajax({

        url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=_MY_API_KEY_",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
          var widget = show(data);

          $("#show").html(widget);

          $("#city").val('');
        }

      });
    } else {
      $("#error").html('Field cannot be empty');
    }
  });
});

function show(data) {
  return '<h3><strong>Weather<strong>: ' + data.weather[0].main + ' </h3>' +
    '<h3><strong>Weather<strong>: ' + data.weather[0].description + ' </h3>';
}

console.log('hello')
```

```css
.mainArea {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.day1,
.day2,
.day3,
.day4,
.day5 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.input {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation Bar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light jumbotron">
    <div class="navbar-brand">Weather Guide</a>
      <!-- <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="inputValue form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search City" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="button btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" value="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>-->
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="text-center text-primary">Enter City Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='row form-group form-inline'>
      <input tyepe='text' name='city' id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="city name">
      <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>

    <div id="show">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content -->




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the prior revisions.

Answer (score 1):

$('submitWeather') should be $('#submitWeather')

Comment: Very welcome :) May I request that you please accept the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without jquery incase anybody wants it:

```js
const getCity = () => document.querySelector('input#city').value || "austin"

document.querySelector("#getWeather").addEventListener('click', function () {
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${getCity()}&units=metric&APPID=_MY_API_KEY_`
  
  loadDataRequest(url, displayJSON)
})

function loadDataRequest(url, cb) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cb(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function displayJSON(xhttp) {
  document.querySelector("#show").textContent = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(xhttp.response), null, 2);
}
```

```html
<input id="city" name="city" placeholder="city"/>
<button id="getWeather" type="button" >Get</button>
<div id="show" style="white-space:pre"></div>
```